# How to follow up after this interview? And what does this email mean?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I had an interview with this company on December 19, 2018 (3 weeks ago) and I think it went well. After the interview the interviewer told me that he will send me an email that we will be in touch so if I had any questions, I could ask him during holidays. I didn't receive anything from him, so I sent an email to the HR last week (January 2, 2019) thanking her and asking if she could forward my email to the interviewer so I could follow up with him. Then she replied back with this email :

"I have forwarded your email to Alex and we are currently looking into the employment status."

I don't know what she meant with this email. It's been a week and I haven't heard anything back, and I don't have Alex's contact so I could reach him! I was wondering what should I do now?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @mcknz Also the same user ID (97683/jacob) posted both questions. (Though this is the first of the two.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait. I am sure you are anxious though it hasn’t been that long since you interviewed. Some Talent Management departments are faster than others. If it’s a big company, there are a lot of hoops and checks/balances. Three months is not unheard of in most cases. I wouldn’t contact them again for at least 3-4 weeks if you haven’t heard anything.

Answer (score 3):

You don't state a location - which would have helped.

In some places (I am looking at you, Europe), many people take 2, even 3, weeks holiday at xmas (and then another week to get back into the groove when they return to work).

In any case, while it seems an eternity of waiting for you, it usually takes a few weeks to make an offer, even to a single candidate. If there are other applicants who might not yet even have been interviewed, it could take longer.

Also, "employment status" sounds like there might be a visa or work permit involved. Is his the case?

As always, the motto is to keep looking, even after an offer, right up to the moment that you sign a contract.

Answer (score 1):

> I had an interview with this company on December 19, 2018 (3 weeks ago) ... It's been a week and I haven't heard anything back, and I don't have Alex's contact so I could reach him!

You interviewed just before Christmas - you can pretty much write off at least a couple of weeks after this time in terms of hearing back. Things move really slowly over this time period, and only pick up properly again mid-January time (since employees invariably have to catch up on a lot when they return.)

> I was wondering what should I do now?

You carry on what you should be doing in any case if you're looking for work / internships and haven't received a firm offer in writing - you keep interviewing and applying to other relevant jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> I have forwarded your email to Alex and we are currently looking into the employment status.

They are intending taking on an intern, but they don't have things signed off for this yet, so even if they are interested in you they can't move until the appropriate person signs off on the role.

Even if you are not being paid (or earning little as an intern) there is still a cost to a business (facilities, computer etc).  Given it's year start, they may be in a new financial year which can delay things until budgets are agreed, (or not).

It's a waiting game, and keep looking, these things are never settled until they are, so don't hold out for one until it's a done deal (this will happen with going for jobs throughout your career).

Comment: Sorry, but where did you get "intern" from in your answer? I don't see it mentioned in the question or any comments that the position is an internship.

Comment: It's tagged internship (and no edits so by the OP) , is that incorrect?

Comment: Nope, you're right - I hadn't seen the tag. Thanks for clarifying.