# Following up an interview after one month

Tags: interviewing, internship

I had an interview with this company on December 19, 2018 and I think it went well. After the interview the interviewer told me that he will send me an email that we will be in touch so if I had any questions, I could ask him during holidays. I didn't receive anything from him, so I sent an email to the HR on January 2, 2019, thanking her and asking if she could forward my email to the interviewer so I could follow up with him. Then she replied back with this email :

"I have forwarded your email to Alex and we are currently looking into the employment status."

Since then I haven't heard back from the company (neither the interviewer or the HR). So I was wondering when is a good time to follow up with them.

Thanks

P.S. Update:
I contacted them and they told me they decided not to go forward with my application. It's definitely better than waiting.

Comment: Any other time of the year I would say move on but it could be that some people are still on holidays.

Comment: This seems to be a near duplicate of your other question on Workplace: If you had intended to update that one, you might be better off doing so, rather than posting a duplicate: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126035/how-to-follow-up-after-this-interview-and-what-does-this-email-mean

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you already followed up properly and have not heard since. One month is most likely past the line to assume you will not hear anything back. Unfortunately radio silencing rejected candidates is more common than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Usually my time frame is two weeks after the interview to the hiring manager after I haven't heard from the company.  I will send them an email or call to see what the status is if I haven't heard anything, and if they don't reply after that, chances are their silence is their tacit message they aren't moving forward with your application.

Some companies have been good enough to send me a rejection letter the day after I've interviewed, but some companies won't send rejection letters until months after they've hired someone; the good companies will keep your resume on file and encourage you to apply elsewhere.

From a personal standpoint: I absolutely refuse to hound employers, even if I really was interested in the position, because they could still be interviewing.  If they want to hire me, they'll contact me sooner than later.  Radio silence, on the other hand, is rude but commonplace.